# Can Izanagi help to escape natural death?

Tags: naruto

As far as I understand Izanami determines the fate and Izanagi helps to escape the fate in cost of a Sharingan. Death is the ultimate fate of all of us. So can Izanagi be used to cheat natural death. Then a Rinnegan and Sharingan wielder can be virtually immortal!
Can Izanagi cheat natural death.

Comment: I don't think so, since you can use the izanagi for a very short duration even if you could evade natural death at the moment, after the time has expired you will die. So its only a temporarily solution, but for that duration you can say you are immortal. Well at least from what i understand, but i am not that deep into Naruto lore

Comment: first of all i just want to know, meaning of the term "natural death", do mean getting old, body doesn't work well, sick and die or other

Comment: Izanami and Izanagi are two of the most complicated techniques in the universe. If you want immortality, just ask to be resurrected after you die. It's possible.

Answer (score 1):

*PARTLY SPOILER* 
Yes, you can use the Izangi to revive yourself after death. I don't know how, but Madara had implanted the Izangi in his eye before his death and used it to come back to life, for exchange for his right eye.